# simple example of connecting a tcp socket to spring integration

Tags: sockets, spring-integration

Does anyone know of a simple example of connecting to a web server using spring integration using a tcp socket?  There are examples of simple socket communications in plain java with both the server and client instances.  There are also examples of connecting a client to server entirely in spring integration.  However, in my attempts to make a simple socket connection to a spring integration gateway by a plain java app the spring side sees the connection but fails out with a max message length exception.  So far I cannot find an example that connects these 2 types together.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the max message length property to more than the default of 2048 bytes?

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at [Using UDP and TCP Adapters in Spring Integration 2.0 M3](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/03/29/using-udp-and-tcp-adapters-in-spring-integration-2-0-m3/).